# Short pulse of monochromatic light?

Tags: visible-light, laser, fourier-transform

(Potentially connected to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/311663/existence-of-monochromatic-pulses), but could not find the answer to my particular question there.)

The frequency spread and time duration of a pulse are related by:

$$ \Delta \omega \Delta t \approx 2 \pi, $$

from which perfectly monochromatic radiation ($\Delta \omega$ = 0) would require an infinite "pulse", $\Delta t \rightarrow \infty$.

**Now**: let's think of a (locked) CW laser, emitting a stable frequency with a linewidth of ~10s of kHz. Actually let's even assume 0 linewidth, let's assume it's ideal.

I have a shutter (or some other sort of switch) in the beam path, that goes ON and then OFF in a very short amount of time (100s of µs). Because of the finite duration of the pulse, I now have a spread in frequencies, following the Fourier relations.

So there are photons with a little bit more and a little bit less energy than originally. How? What's the interaction that allowed the reshuffling in energy?

Comment: The shutter introduces a time dependent interaction.

Comment: Did you observe the spread of frequencies or is it a pure theoretical question?

Comment: Perhaps you want to read about [Existence of monochromatic pulses](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/312113/46708)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shutter for a light source  is a kind of inverse field generator,
that results in nil electric oscillation when it blocks the light.   Logically,
that means that the shutter is a kind of secondary radiation source, and even
if the laser is continuous, your shutter is adding a time-dependent
bunch of secondary radiation.

Comment: These type of considerations are reasonably clear and are about as far as this non-specialist got. But I would love to know if there is a tractable toy model to use for first approximation calculations.

Comment: What's "nil"? Do you have anything a bit more quantitative?

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you bring photons into the question, you should also bring quantum mechanics. The shutter constrains the photon's position, thereby introducing uncertainty in its momentum [equivalently, energy]. Note that this is just $\hbar$ times your original statement.

Comment: But isn't the laser alrady ensuring the beam is collimated and of a definite spot-size? My shutter is >> size of the beam.